Angular sending a simple message: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' / 'path'
I'm encountering an issue with communication between my Angular front-end and Electron back-end using IPC. When attempting to send a message from my Angular component to my Electron main process, I'm getting the following error:
./node_modules/electron/index.js:1:11-24 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/user/Desktop/project/node_modules/electron'

./node_modules/electron/index.js:2:13-28 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/user/Desktop/project/node_modules/electron'

main.js
const {app, ipcMain} = require('electron');
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
const url = require("url");
const path = require("path");

let window

function createWindow () {
    window = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        autoHideMenuBar: true,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    });

    window.setMinimumSize(800, 600);

    window.loadURL( 
        url.format({
            pathname: path.join(__dirname, `/dist/music-converter/index.html`),
            protocol: "file:",
            slashes: true
        })
    );
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})

app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
})

ipcMain.on('message-from-renderer', (event, arg) => {
    console.log(arg);
    event.reply('message-from-main', 'Message received in main process'); 
});

Angular
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ipcRenderer } from 'electron'

@Component({
  selector: 'file-browser',
  templateUrl: './file-browser.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./file-browser.component.scss']
})

export class FileBrowserComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    ipcRenderer.send('message-from-renderer', 'test');
  }
}


Additional Context
Electron: 30.0.1
Angular: 16.2.0


I tried another import approach:

if ((<any>window).require) {
   this.ipcRenderer = (<any>window).require('electron').ipcRenderer;
}

or
ngOnInit() {
   if ((<any>window).require) {
      const electron = (<any>window).require('electron');
      electron.ipcRenderer.send('message-from-renderer', 'test');
  } else {
     console.error('Electron is not available');
  }
}


Configuration of webpack.config.js: npm install path-browserify

const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            fs: 'empty',
            path: 'empty'
        })
    ]
};

or
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      fs: false,
      path: require.resolve('path-browserify')
    }
  }
};


Changing the package.json by adding:

"requires": true,
"browser": {
  "fs": false,
  "path": false,
  "os": false
}


Using a preload script:
preload.js

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

main.js
window = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        autoHideMenuBar: true,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    });

I've experimented with various approaches and iterations of the suggested solutions, but I must admit that I'm feeling a bit overwhelmed. As someone who's new to working with Electron and Angular, I'm finding myself in over my head and any help is appreciated.

It looks electron could not find node.js. Did you install it?

This question is similar to: How to solve this error Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
